# How to evaluate $\int x^{5/2}\sqrt{1+x}dx$?

Tags: integration

$$\int x^{5/2}\sqrt{1+x}dx \,$$

I don't know how to start. I tried with a change of variable $t=\sqrt{x+1}$.

EDIT:[image: Snapshot from the solution manual]

EDIT2: I don't know how to get to $\frac{1}{4}x^{5/2}(1+x)^{3/2} - \int \frac{5}{12}x^{3/2}\sqrt{1+x} dx$.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not something I would consider [solvable by hand](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+x%5E%285%2F4%29*sqrt%28x%2B1%29+dx), unless WA misses some really big simplification.

Comment: $dx$ is missing.

Comment: Yep, you're right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is equivalent to a so-called [incomplete Beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) integral. From Wolfram Integrator output, you can suspect that it is irreducible (cannot be expressed in elementary functions).

**This answer is based on a former problem statement.**

---

**Hint on the current problem**:

The integrand is of the form
$$x^p\sqrt{1+x}.$$

Integrating by parts on $\sqrt{1+x}$, you will get a term $x^p(1+x)^{3/2}$ and a new integrand $x^{p-1}(1+x)^{3/2}$ (coefficients ignored).

Then decomposing $(1+x)^{3/2}=(1+x)\sqrt{1+x}$, you will get a sum of integrands $x^{p-1}\sqrt{1+x}$ and $x^p\sqrt{1+x}$. Moving the latter to the LHS, you have achieved a reduction from $p$ to $p-1$.

$$\int x^p\sqrt{1+x}\,dx=\frac2{3+2p}x^p(1+x)^{3/2}-\frac{2p}{3+2p}\int x^{p-1}\sqrt{1+x}\,dx.$$

Repeating twice, you end up with

$$\int \sqrt x\sqrt{1+x}\,dx,$$ which you can solve using $2x+1=\cosh(t)$.

Comment: I have the answer in the solution manual. I'll try to upload a snapshot

Comment: I have weakened my statement.

Comment: I added the pic. I tried by parts, $f=x^{5/4}$ and $g' = \sqrt{1+x}$. I didn't work either.

Comment: Hem, $5/2$, not $5/4$ !

Comment: Yes, I screwed it up. I wrote $x^{5/4}$ instead of $x^{5/2}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\int x^{\frac{5}{2}}\sqrt{1+x}\space\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=\sqrt{x}$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\space\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$2\int u^6\sqrt{u^2+1}\space\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Substitute $u=\tan(s)$ and $\text{d}u=\sec^2(s)\space\space\text{d}s$:

---

$$2\int \tan^6(s)\sec^3(s)\space\space\text{d}s=$$
$$2\int \sec^3(s)(\sec^2(s)-1)^3\space\space\text{d}s=$$
$$2\int \left(\sec^9(s)-3\sec^7(s)+3\sec^5(s)-\sec^3(s)\right)\space\space\text{d}s=$$
$$2\left(\int\sec^9(s)\space\space\text{d}s-3\int\sec^7(s)\space\space\text{d}s+3\int\sec^5(s)\space\space\text{d}s-\int\sec^3(s)\space\space\text{d}s\right)$$